# Simplify a convex hull

Tags: algorithm, opencv

My problem is as follows:
I have a convex hull which could look like this:
[image: Raw convex hull]

I would like to group significantly close points together to be represented by *some form of averaging*, which could be the mean or median point for example.
[image: averaged convex hull]

I am more so focused on how to do the grouping.

How can I perform this grouping in a systematic way?

I understand this seems like a very simple question and the answer is obvious. My main problem is in attempts to solve this I end up with some corner cases such as the answer will change depending on where I start on the hull. For example if I started from the red line and worked clockwise I would end up with (if I made no attempt to catch the corner case):

[image: starting from here][image]

I had many attempts at this and every time I rethought my idea I ended up with a new corner case that felt unwieldy. I have a habit of finding the most un-intuitive way to solve a problem so I thought it best to ask the a community. A comparative example to the problem I am having now is I've been asked to find an element in a sorted array and I'm initially performing a linear search and I have a gut feeling there is something better out there.

I could not find exactly what I wanted with my research. I found hull simplifying algorithms but it changed the shape of the hull too much which did not suit the goal of my program.

I will add a note here at the end that I am using OpenCV with C++ to generate a convex hull on a project I am working on. Just in case this is a worth while detail (and why I added OpenCV as a tag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

It is intended to simplify polylines, throwing out less important points.

Thanks Berriel for addition: it is implemented in OpenCV: [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp)

[image]

Comment: And it is already implemented in OpenCV: [`approxPolyDP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp)

Comment: Dear @MBo, does `approxPolyDP` make sure none of the interior of the original hull is lost? Can I be assured that it only expands the hull and does not cut away from it?

Comment: @Michael Sohnen This function removes part of old vertices because documentation says it uses Douglas Peucker algo

Comment: Is there a version where it will add new vertices in addition to eliminating old ones?

Comment: @Michael Sohnen Sorry, I don't know. This method was intended to remove maximal number of points, so it would be strange to add excessive points. Perhaps another algorothms do exist to make new polyline without using old points (like linear least squares to approximate by one line segment)

Comment: @MBo Thanks. When I used OpenCV's `approxPolyDP`, it did seem to "cut in" to the original region. However, when the epsilon is small, the effect is not too bad, and I still can simplify my polygon by a factor of 10. From some basic online searching, it seems as though simplifying the curve with the constraint of ensuring no area loss is not a trivial problem.